# add th cells from c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I create a table with headers of 2 levels, the first heading is created programmatically, and the second one with asp.net HeaderText.

I need to capture the headers of the vvurhu while scrolling. Found a fix solution but for th. the question is whether it is possible from C # code to indicate that the cell is not td but th

```
GridViewRow gridViewRow1 = new GridViewRow(-1, -1, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Insert);
TableCell tableCell1 = new TableCell();
tableCell1.ColumnSpan = 9;
tableCell1.Text = "ПРИБЫТИЕ по железной дороге";
tableCell1.CssClass = "centre_align_red";
gridViewRow1.Cells.Add(tableCell1);
```

Or need to look for another solution??

[image]
I have such a hat of 3 lines, how can I fix it, tried different options, but there is a shift of the merged cells

```
.table-scrolGridTerminal tr:nth-child(1) {
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
    }
.table-scrolGridTerminal tr:nth-child(2) {
    position: sticky;
    top: 25px;
}
.table-scrolGridTerminal tr:nth-child(3) {
    position: sticky;
    top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a TableHeaderCell instead of a TableCell?

Comment: yes TableHeaderCell

Comment: Thank you your answer already gave me a hint